# How re- position the expanded images in colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I'm new to colorbox!
I looked around for a good lightbox - and eventually selected colorbox.

But the issue is I need to position the background (I think it's #cboxOverlay) over to the left by 120px.  i.e. so the original page still shows a bit beneath.

```
#cboxOverlay{background:#abc;    left:120px; )
```

Seems to work,

But how do I re-position the expanded images so that they are in the center of the (new size of background).  Currently it's in the center of the screen.
I've tried lots of css changes, but without a meaningful solution.

```
#colorbox{ ... margin:auto !important;}
```

Doesnt seem to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions please.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

To center an object with the `margin: 0 auto;` trick you need 3 key properties:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block / table / box;
width: [anythingOtherThanAuto];
```

### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp2BT/1/)

Other options include:

```
transform: translateX(50%);
```

or my personal favorite (that wouldn't help you much but it's nice to know):

```
position: relative / absolute / fixed;
right: 15%;
left: 15%;
top: 15%;
bottom: 15%;
```

That's more of a..."I need to fit an overlay background perfectly"...kinda thing.

Comment: But I don't know the size (width) of the picture.  i.e. ColorBox allows pics of differing sizes, centering each without need for me to specify each size.
So would I but for 'width' in your your example:
  width: [anythingOtherThanAuto];

Comment: a percentage.  You can use something like `max-width: 80%;` in the `#margin` div and `max-width: 100%;` for the `img`.  Here's an example for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/wYjBR/

Comment: Sorry I can't see where to apply this to colorBox.
Below is their colorbox.css   I have highlighted where I have moved the Overlay left by 120px.   But which/how do re-center #colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the css here  (don't know where else to put such a long bit of code.
Sorry I can't see where to apply this to colorBox.
Below is their colorbox.css   I have highlighted where I have moved the Overlay left by 120px.   But which/how do re-center #colorbox.

```
'code'
/*
    Colorbox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxWrapper {max-width:none;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of Colorbox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#fff;     left:120px; <!-- CHANGED --> }
#colorbox{outline:0;}
    #cboxContent{margin-top:32px; overflow:visible; background:#000;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{background:#000; padding:1px;}
        #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#000;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; top:-22px; left:0; color:#000;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; top:-22px; right:205px; text-indent:-9999px;}

        /* these elements are buttons, and may need to have additional styles reset to avoid unwanted base styles */
        #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:visible; text-indent:-9999px; width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:-20px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 0;}

        /* avoid outlines on :active (mouseclick), but preserve outlines on :focus (tabbed navigating) */
        #cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active {outline:0;}

        #cboxPrevious{background-position:0px 0px; right:44px;}
        #cboxPrevious:hover{background-position:0px -25px;}
        #cboxNext{background-position:-25px 0px; right:22px;}
        #cboxNext:hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}
        #cboxClose{background-position:-50px 0px; right:0;}
        #cboxClose:hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxPrevious, .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxPrevious{right:66px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-75px -25px; right:44px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow:hover{background-position:-100px -25px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-100px 0px; right:44px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow:hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}


'code'
```